# Многопоточная работа с аккаунтами telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Всем здравствуйте! Не могу разобраться: не получается запустить мой скрипт, в котором сообщение должно отправляться с нескольких аккаунтов одновременно. Выдает длинную ошибку, не могу понять в чем дело. Прикрепляю скрипт:

```
import time
from threading import Thread
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync
import asyncio

api_hash = '1cccb9434e585aeхххb29d4ab8ххх504'
api_id = 19910ххх

usernamed = '@юзернейм'


def sleepMe(i):
    client = TelegramClient(f'accounts/account{str(i)}', api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash, app_version="10 P (28)", device_model="Iphone", system_version='6.12.0')
    client.start()
    client.send_message(usernamed, '/start')
    client.disconnect()

for i in range(5):
    th = Thread(target=sleepMe, args=(i, ))
    th.start()
```

Содержание ошибки:

```
Exception in thread Exception in thread Exception in thread Thread-1Thread-2Thread-3:
:
:
Exception in thread Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Thread-4  File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()self.run()

      File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
      File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
self.run()self.run()

  File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
  File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

  File "c:\Users\WNPKV\Desktop\TEST\potoki.py", line 13, in sleepMe
      File "c:\Users\WNPKV\Desktop\TEST\potoki.py", line 13, in sleepMe
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)client = TelegramClient(f'accounts/account{str(i)}', api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash, app_version="10 P (28)", device_model="Iphone", system_version='6.12.0')


  File "c:\Users\WNPKV\Desktop\TEST\potoki.py", line 13, in sleepMe
  File "c:\Users\WNPKV\Desktop\TEST\potoki.py", line 13, in sleepMe
client = TelegramClient(f'accounts/account{str(i)}', api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash, app_version="10 P (28)", device_model="Iphone", system_version='6.12.0')  File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\telegrambaseclient.py", line 320, in __init__

          File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\telegrambaseclient.py", line 320, in __init__
client = TelegramClient(f'accounts/account{str(i)}', api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash, app_version="10 P (28)", device_model="Iphone", system_version='6.12.0')client = TelegramClient(f'accounts/account{str(i)}', api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash, app_version="10 P (28)", device_model="Iphone", system_version='6.12.0')
    if not callable(getattr(self.loop, 'sock_connect', None)):      File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\telegrambaseclient.py", line 320, in __init__


if not callable(getattr(self.loop, 'sock_connect', None)):  File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\telegrambaseclient.py", line 320, in __init__  
  File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\telegrambaseclient.py", line 472, in loop

      File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\telegrambaseclient.py", line 472, in loop
if not callable(getattr(self.loop, 'sock_connect', None)):
if not callable(getattr(self.loop, 'sock_connect', None)):  File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\telegrambaseclient.py", line 472, in loop      

      File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\telegrambaseclient.py", line 472, in loop
return asyncio.get_event_loop()
return asyncio.get_event_loop()
return asyncio.get_event_loop()  File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 642, in get_event_loop
Exception in thread   File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 642, in get_event_loop

    Thread-5:
return asyncio.get_event_loop()  File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 642, in get_event_loop
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'  File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 642, in get_event_loop
raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'

raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'RuntimeError
RuntimeError:     self.run(): There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'.    RuntimeError
There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.
raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.':   File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run


There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-3'.RuntimeError
: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-4'.
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\WNPKV\Desktop\TEST\potoki.py", line 13, in sleepMe
    client = TelegramClient(f'accounts/account{str(i)}', api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash, app_version="10 P (28)", device_model="Iphone", system_version='6.12.0')
  File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\telegrambaseclient.py", line 320, in __init__
    if not callable(getattr(self.loop, 'sock_connect', None)):
  File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\telegrambaseclient.py", line 472, in loop
    return asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "C:\Users\WNPKV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 642, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-5'.
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Дополните, пожалуйста, вопрос указанием сообщения "длинной ошибки". Возможно, именно в сообщении указано, в чём именно дело и что "ломается" у вас.

Comment: Дополнил содержимым ошибки